# Editing and running HTML and CSS code through Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio

I am trying to edit and run my HTML, CSS, and Javascript code through VS 2013 and have successfully added all of my existing files to my project. When I try to run the HTML file in order to test it, I get the dreaded HTTP Forbidden 403 error in the browser.

I have tried this in both Google Chrome and Internet Explorer with the same results in both. Did I set up the solution wrong? Or is there some sort of setting I must fiddle with in Visual Studio?

Comment: Just to make sure, this is when running the website from within the VS (with F5 or Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: Yep. We do the same thing in my class and it works there but not on my computer at home.

Comment: Do you have the same software installed? SQL Server springs to mind.

Comment: I should. At home I have web essentials. Not sure about any SQL software as I have no experience with it.